# Field Calculator GUID remove curly brackets from GUID string

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm attempting to Field Calculate the GlobalID field into a text-equivalent version of it, named GlobalID_T. This new text field will have the exact values for records calculated into it, except for the curly brackets at the beginning and end of the number string. All values the same for all records except the curly brackets. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include info about any attempts you've made and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In field calculator for field `GlobalID_T` switch to the Python Parser and enter

```
!GlobalID![1:-1]
```

This will take the value in the `GlobalID` field and remove the first and last character (your curly brackets).

[image]

Result in the attribute table:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to better understand how this scripting works, so I typed the following:
!GlobalID![1]     clicked OK... and
!GlobalID![-1]     clicked OK
I noticed that in the first example, the first character inside the first curly bracket was returned. However, in the second example, the last curly bracket itself was returned. This does not seem consistent, could you explain this one a little more?

Comment: @Michael Look into string slicing in Python.  See [An Informal Introduction to Python - Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).  While playing with these values, trying using `!GlobalID![1:]` and `!GlobalID![:-1]`, and also trying changing the numbers to see the different results - `!GlobalID![5]`, `!GlobalID![2:-5]` etc.